# Is ok to create a custom validator that should run a query to validate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to validate the membership card number of a table to be unique only for current year, so I must build a custom validator for my model column.

My questions are:

- Is heavy to make a query to check for uniqueness in current year every time I update/create a single row? How am I expected to deal
  with this?
- I used custom validators only on CakePHP, can you post a stupid example only to show me a syntax example?

**Edit 1:**

Notice that the *current year* is stored in a column called `expire_date` which is a year-month-day date format.
The check should be performed only for the year however.
How can I deal with this? That's why I suppose I should use a custom validator, I think `scope` shouldn't work in this case.

**Edit 2:**

I just noticed a `:if` option, I'll check if I can implement this through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 provides syntax sugar, so you can do something like this:

```
validates :car_number, :uniqueness => {:scope => :expire_year, :message => 'has already been taken this year'}, :on => :update

def expire_year
  expire_date.strftime("%Y")
end
```

How the query heavy is depends on DB schema and load. Don't forget to setup an index on year column and check the rails logs.

Note this will work for update only, because new object doesn't have the timestamps populated until save.

Comment: actually I think the index should be on [:card_number, :year]. But it's better to test it and see wich columns are used in the query for uniqueness

Comment: yes, true, single-columns indexes are with implicit primary-key, so SQL EXPLAIN can show what the index suitable best

Comment: mh I have a "problem", my "year" is stored in a column called "expire_date" which contains a full date, how can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord already have that!

```
validates_uniqueness_of :car_number, :scope => :year
```

Docs for [validates_uniqueness_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)